# solution of fuctional equation: $f(g(x))=x^2$.

Tags: functional-equations, inverse-function

For any $x \in (1,+\infty)$, $f(g(x))=x^2$, $g(f(x))=x^4$.

How to find the $f(x)$， $g(x)$ statisfying above functional equation.

Suppose inverse function existed.

The problem can be simplified to $f^2(x)=f(x^4)$.

How to find $f(x)$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik the problem can be simplified to finding f(x), satisfying $f^2(x)=f(x^4)$

Comment: As with any equation involving two unknowns, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $(1,+\infty)$ is included in the domain. Is it all of the domain?

Comment: @user247327 this might be a helpful heuristic, but definitely not a theorem, ($x^2 + y^2 = -1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ has no solution).

Comment: @user247327 one feasible solution is enough.

Comment: @user247327: there are in fact two infinities of equations.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $x=e^{4^t}$, $f^2(x)=f(x^4)$ turns to

$$2\log(f(e^{4^t}))=\log(f(e^{4^{t+1}}))$$ which is of the form

$$h(t+1)=2h(t),$$

and has the solution

$$h(t)=2^th_0.$$

So $$\log(f(x))=2^{\log_4(\log(x))}h_0=\sqrt{\log(x)}h_0$$

and finally,

$$f(x)=e^{\sqrt{\log(x)}h_0}=a_0^{\sqrt{\log(x)}}.$$

---

**Technical note:**

In fact, $a_0$ is not a constant. As the recurrence is given for values of $t$ one unit apart, $a_0(t)$ can be defined freely in any interval of unit length, such as $[t_0,t_0+1)$. This corresponds to a free definition of $f$ in $[x_0,x_0^4)$.

Comment: This downvote deserves an explanation.

Comment: Great! Let $f(x)=e^\sqrt{\ln x}$,then $g(x)=x^{4ln x}$, which is one feasible solution to the question.

Comment: @Nine: er, no, with my definition, $g(t)=2^t$. But you directly check that $$e^{\sqrt{\log x^4}}=e^{\sqrt{4\log x}}=e^{2\sqrt{\log x}}=(e^{\sqrt{\log x}})^2.$$

Comment: I mean the solution to my original question.

Comment: @Nine: ooops, sorry, I realize that I have cause much confusion by using $g$ for my temporary function. Fixing...

Answer (score 0):

Solving
$$
f(x)^2 = f(x^4) .
\tag{1}$$

We do not require that $f$ be continuous!

Let $f$ be arbitrary $[2,2^4) \to (1,+\infty)$.  Extend recursively:

For $x \in [2^4,2^{4^2})$, let $f(x) = f(\sqrt[4]{x}\;)^2$.  This means that $f$ satisfies $(1)$ for $x \in [2,2^{4})$.

For $x \in [2^{4^2}, 2^{4^3})$, let $f(x) = f(\sqrt[4]{x}\;)^2$.  This means that $f$ satisfies $(1)$ for $x \in [2^4,2^{4^2})$.

Continue in this way: for $x>2^4$ define $f(x) = f(\sqrt[4]{x}\;)^2$.

In the other direction:  For $x \in [2^{4^{-1}},2)$, let
$f(x) = \sqrt{f(x^4)}$. This means that $f$ satisfies $(1)$ for $x \in [2^{4^{-1}},2)$.

For $x \in [2^{4^{-2}},2^{4^{-1}})$, let
$f(x) = \sqrt{f(x^4)}$. This means that $f$ satisfies $(1)$ for $x \in [2^{4^{-2}},2^{4^{-1}})$.

Continue in this way:  For $1 < x < 2$ define $f(x) = \sqrt{f(x^4)}$.